# How do I mix javascript and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

This may seem like a really silly question, but I learned jQuery and Javascript separate from each other, and there are elements of each that I prefer over the other. My nesting with jQuery can get messy really quickly, so I'd like to write mostly in Javascript, but some things about jQuery come easier and quicker to me, like the events. Can I mix the two? And if so, what's the proper syntax?
As an example, if I wanted to do something like the following, would it work? The .click function is jQuery, while the rest is written in Javascript.

```
if(.click(#button)){
```

Comment: I'd love to know how you plan to get a random number with jQuery, which is a DOM manipulation tool... then again, [there's plugins for everything](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif) so...

Comment: `mix javascript and jquery` jQuery ***is*** JavaScript. The `.click` function is **a method provided by jQuery**, which is a library written in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes you can mix them. No that code will not work. Would need something like
$('#button').click(function() { // Can write whatever JavaScript you want here });

Answer (score 1):

jquery is JavaScript, so yes go ahead and mix them.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript and jQuery are always mixed because you write jQuery code in JavaScript. JavaScript is the language, while jQuery is a library for JavaScript.

I'm guessing you mean how do you mix jQuery code with native JavaScript selectors or api calls. They should be work well together because, as mentioned, ultimately you're writing JavaScript.

Comment: Is it wrong to be amused that an answer that is cut-off got an immediate upvote? [Screenshot for posterity](http://prntscr.com/2hpzky)

Comment: No it's not, I don't know what happened.  Weird, anyways I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I think I worded my question wrong. I guess what I meant was how to incorporate them together in a way that's syntactically correct. Ted A. commented well, and I guess I should have tried that first. I don't really like writing out jQuery syntax, but my first instinct is to just insert the events without thinking it through. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @user3070406 - I don't really understand how you can not know how to use `.click` since there are [plenty of examples](http://api.jquery.com/click/) in the jQuery documentation...

Comment: It's not that I don't know how to use .click, I know full well how to use it in the realm of jQuery, but I was wondering if I could insert it into Javascript the way I did and still have the program understand me. Either way, there's no need to be pretentious.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery and Javascript are the same thing - JQuery is a library written in Javascript. So yes you can "mix" them.